# iOS Nuke, how to use loadImage with completion for activity indicator

Tags: swift3

I am using Nuke 4.1.2 to download and set an image to a cell image in a UITableView.

This works fine but no activity indicator.

```
if let url = URL(string: imageUrl) {                   
    Nuke.loadImage(with: url, into: cell.itemImage)
}
```

If I try this I get the errors listed below.

```
cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()

if let url = URL(string: imageUrl) {                                 
   Nuke.loadImage(with: url, into: cell.itemImage) { [weak cell.itemImage] in
   cell.itemImage.handle(response: $0, isFromMemoryCache: $1)
   cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()      
}
```

errors:

```
fields may only be captured by assigning to a specific name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()

let cellImageView = cell.imageView

Nuke.loadImage(with: url, into: cellImageView) { [weak cellImageView] in
cellImageView?.handle(response: $0, isFromMemoryCache: $1)

cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
```